# MySQL configuration for Spring boot micro-services

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am building  multiple project using spring boot which are connected to single MySQL instance. so I am facing some problems in a transaction.

From one spring boot instance when i am updating some records on one table and i am retrieving other records from same table with another spring boot instance its waiting until the transaction completes on first instance then it will fetch the records and return it.

i want to retrieve the other records (not updating records) while the table has some records which is updating. So what is the best solution for this and what is the configuration i need to change it in MySQL and spring boot as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing single Mysql instance from multiple projects is a common thing. This won't block your transaction as far as you are not fetching resources which are already in transaction. i.e. which are updating. As when a query fire MySQL will lock that object until transaction completes.

> What you need to do is to handle via **@Transactional** annotation. From **javax.transaction.Transactional** package at service layer and spring boot will handle it automatically.

It should work!!